# MySQL FullText search returns 0 if multiple row matches

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

`Match` / `Against` returns true if I pass unique value in query and returns 0 if I pass value, which exist in multiple row.

```
SELECT MATCH(b.branch_name) 
AGAINST ('Men' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE ), branch_name 
FROM `branch` AS `b` WHERE 1

Table Data:
id   | branch_name
--------------------
1    | Men 
2    | Beauty
3    | Women
```

If I pass `MATCH(b.branch_name) AGAINST ('Men' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE )` returns 0 for all row,
If I pass `MATCH(b.branch_name) AGAINST ('Women' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE )` returns > 0 value same for `'beauty'`

Can anyone please help me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a system variable called `ft_min_word_len` whose default value is 4 (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)).

That means that words of less than four letters are ignored -- not included in the index.  No entry in the index; no rows returned.

Reset the value and then rebuild the index so "men" will be in the index.  Then your query will work.

Comment: So how I can modify that value in query?